# How to add documentation to NuGet 4.x+ package using VS2017?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I've read guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2017), but I couldn't find how to add my generated on build xml documentation file. We used to reference files in old `.nuspec` files `<file></file>` tag, but I can't find the equivalent of it.

From what I understood, it seems that if I create xml file on build it should automatically be added to NuGet, but when I examine my nuget after downloading it, it is still without xml documentation.

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.5</VersionPrefix>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.5</PackageVersion>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;net461</TargetFrameworks>
    <AssemblyName>SBTech.ApiUtils</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>SBTech.ApiUtils</PackageId>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Dev|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Dev\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Staging|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Staging\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net461|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\net461\SBTech.ApiUtils.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net461|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\net461\SBTech.ApiUtils.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Staging|net461|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Staging\net461\SBTech.ApiUtils.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Dev|net461|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Dev\net461\SBTech.ApiUtils.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|netcoreapp1.1|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\SBTech.ApiUtils.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|netcoreapp1.1|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\SBTech.ApiUtils.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Staging|netcoreapp1.1|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Staging\netcoreapp1.1\SBTech.ApiUtils.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Dev|netcoreapp1.1|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Dev\netcoreapp1.1\SBTech.ApiUtils.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This adds xml files to my packages, however when I inspect the code of the package from within the client project xml documentation is not shown in VS.

Comment: what about this issue? Could you get useful information from Martin`s answer? I test it works fine on my side. If it not what you want, please share us more info about this issue.

Comment: Indeed my VS was 15.2 version, but after upgrading it, issue remained, I am editing my question with my project file. @Leo-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you update to VS 2017 version 15.3 or higher and the .NET Core 2.0.0 SDK ("CLI") - or mono 5.2 on macOS / linux - this will be done automatically once the `csproj` is set to generate the xml documentation (via the `GenerateDocumentationFile` property being set to `true`).

Specifically, this has been fixed [as part of this pull request](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/1255) for NuGet 4.3.0

Comment: I've edited my question, I think I am doing something else wrong, since I updated my studio from 15.2 to 15.3 and issue still remains.

Comment: I tested it and it worked fine when I create a project with your properties. do you have the 2.0.0 SDK installed and made sure there is no `global.json` that sets a lower sdk version?